# Feeling the Breeze

Tags: fluid-dynamics

This question is based on an odd phenomenon I noticed last week. Since then, I've been collecting more data to try to get an accurate picture of the facts.

Each morning, I go to my bus stop. It's on a main road, and when I get there, there is a lot of traffic. Every couple minutes a large truck goes by, and I suddenly feel a breeze go by me. The catch here is that there is about a one-second delay between the truck passing by and the start of the breeze. What is causing this phenomenon?

Here's some more information: I'm about three meters from the road; The breeze begins roughly one second after the truck passes by, and last for one and a half seconds; The breeze seems to be blowing diagonally, from my rear left to my front right side (I'm in America, so the trucks go from left to right); The breeze does not seem to depend on truck size (although small vehicles do not cause it).

I do have two possible explanations for the breeze:

1) The truck goes by at about 30 mph. This could create a tiny, short-lived vacuum at the back as it moves forward, thereby drawing air towards the rear of the truck.

2) The breeze is the result of some sort of "bow shock" from the truck.

Neither of these explanations seem to satisfy me, though, because they seem a bit far-fetched, and I am certainly no expert in fluid mechanics. What could be the cause of the breeze?

As a last note, I have no idea what tags to use for this question, because I don't know what the cause of the breeze is. Suggestions for these and other edits are welcome.

Comment: Why do you consider those two reasons far fetched? I mean, both of those things happen and are totally consistent with what fluid dynamics predict -- so your intuition is right, but why do you feel it's not?

Comment: It simply seemed odd that the breeze should last so long, when it only took the truck half a second to pass by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're feeling there is the wake behind truck.  As the truck passes through the air, it imparts momentum and generates quite a lot of turbulence (allowing it to impart even more momentum). It takes a little bit of time for that momentum to spread outward and reach you. As that air is 'pulled' behind the truck more will be drawn in from the sides.  These two effects give the flow that left/forward direction that you feel.

The folks at [Cornell](http://energy.mae.cornell.edu/vit.html) have some nice animations and pictures of vehicle wakes.

As fall approaches, try putting some dead leaves (small pieces if possible) out onto the road. They should get caught up in the wake and give you a chance to see this in action.

Your first theory is on the right track. There will be a low pressure region behind the truck (not quite a vacuum). This region will also generally be a swirling mess of turbulence. The this will impart a lot velocity to the air.  The front and sides contribute too, but the back end of a vehicle is usually the most significant source of drag. Check this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_separation), for a nice picture and a bit on flow separation.

Bow shock is less right. You won't see a shock unless you've got things moving around the speed of sound. You will get some acceleration of the flow at the front and sides and that wouldn't look entirely unlike a bow shock, but the wake is the major player.  Unlike a shock, this won't be a sharp interface and it won't be a clean straight line.